# При нажатии кнопки W с помощью класса Robot персонаж не идёт вперёд, в чём проблема?

Tags: java

Для знакомства с классом Robot решил сделать программу, которая бы управляла персонажем из игры Minecraft, но к сожалению данный код не работает в игре.
Буква печатается в блокноте, но не получается заставить персонажа из игры ходить(

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            robot.delay(1000);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Робот генерирует нажатия кнопок ивентами ОС. К сожалению, многие игры используют чуть другой способ контроллирования нажатий (перехват нажатий на более низком уровне, биос, опрос контроллеров, проверка флага программно-сгенерированного события итд).

Варианты имплементации:

1) Написание данного кода для более низкой ступени архитектуры (переписать на другом языке полный функционал либо задействовать JNI для реализации конкретных методов)

2) Патчить саму игру и кидать ивенты непосредственно в неё